# How to use Selenium Webdriver to change location?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape Google results for certain keywords, but when scraping Google I get results based on my location unless I add name of a location onto my keywords and search like this

> [keyword] in Atlanta

This isn't what am trying to accomplish what I want to do is simulate a browser searching google in a certain location so when I enter the keywords in google to search I get results based on that location without defining in my keywords the location. That way I can keep changing locations to see what results appear for each location? How does one accomplish this? I've searched online for a while but can't wrap my head around how this is accomplished and is Selenium-webdriver the right tool?

Answer (score 0):

This js may come in handy:

```
"window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success){
        var position = {'coords' : {
            'latitude': '1234', 
            'longitude': '1234'
        }
    }; 
success(position);}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy and better workarround for this is

(I am assuming that you are parametarizing your keyword to the method)

Give the Location also to the method as parameter. So that you can specify different keyword & location each time.

in side the method:

```
public void googleSearch (String keyword, String location) {
    keyword = keyword + " in " + location;
    //code for searching in google with the above keyword
}
```